# what's worng for my redis "ERR unknown command 'HSTRLEN'"

Tags: hash, redis

```
1)127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET myhash f1 helloword f2 99 f3 -256
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL myhash
2) "f1"
3) "helloword"
4) "f2"
5) "99"
6) "f3"
7) "-256"
127.0.0.1:6379> HSTRLEN myhash f1
(error) ERR unknown command 'HSTRLEN'
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

But this is an official example,[HSTRLEN key field](https://redis.io/commands/hstrlen)what's worng??

Answer (score 0):

Found myself here and discovered this was a version issue:

> https://redis.io/commands/hstrlen
>   Available since 3.2.0.

On Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ redis-server --version
Redis server v=3.0.6

$ sudo apt search redis-server
redis-server/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2:3.0.6-1ubuntu0.3 amd64 [installed]
```

My solution was to run a later version inside docker.